# Search query with current username

Tags: alfresco

I need define fts or lucene query with parameter current logged user, for example I need something like this:

```
ASPECT:'cm:lockable' AND! ASPECT:'cm:workingCopy' AND cm:lockOwner:'getCurrentLoggedUser'
```

I need this query for dashlet creating by saved search , which will show locked files which are locked by logged user.

Is there a way to get a username of current logged user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an expression like that directly in the query.

It won't be difficult to get the authenticated user first and then build the query with string concatenation.

Your dashlet should have a javascript controller where you can use "root" objects. One of them is `person` that is the current authenticated user.

https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.1/develop/reference/repo-root-objects-ref/